# How to make bot count reactions to its and tag everyone who reacted after input amount?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Essentially what I want my bot to do is make a post with a user command given minimum, react to its own post with  and once the minimum amount of reacts with  is met, it posts a new message tagging the person who made the command and everyone else who reacted.

I've tried many things via googling and such and it's not easy to understand because of a lot being non-rewrite. I'm not familiar with python so just looking at the docs didn't help much, and I know if I learned a lot of the basics and essentials to python I'd probably understand but I only want to make this one bot.

```
<code>#imports
import discord
import sys
from discord.ext import commands    
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.') 
annChan = 3333#fake chan num
TOKEN = 3333#fake token
people = []
minPeople = 1
chan = None

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global chan
    chan = bot.get_channel(annChan)
    print('Bot is ready.')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    people.append(ctx.message.author.id) 
    global minPeople
    minPeople = arg2
    msg = await chan.send('<@{}> is looking to go to '.format(ctx.message.author.id)
        + arg1
        + ' and is hoping for '
        + arg2
        + ' other person(s) to come.\nWhen: '
        + arg3
        +'\nReact with :thumbsup: if you\'re interested! @everyone')
    await msg.add_reaction('')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

So far I've only got the bot posting the message given the desired parameters, and reacting to it's own message with .

I can't figure out how to check if the  reaches the amount provided by 'arg2', and then after that is met tagging the creator of the message and all the people who reacted to that message with  letting them know the minimum was met.

I've seen people say use reactions.count but I can't figure out how to do that, nor do I know how to grab everyone that reacted to tag them later.

Appreciate anyone willing to take their time to help me understand and get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command that checks after each reaction if the correct number of people have responded thus far.  You should also give your arguments real names instead of `arg1`, `arg2`.  It's difficult to tell what kind of values those arguments are supposed to be:

```
thumbs_up = "\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}"

def check_count_reaction(emoji, desired_count, message):
    def predicate(reaction, user):
        return reaction.message == message and reaction.emoji == emoji and reaction.count>=desired_count
    return predicate

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, destination, number: int, condition):
    msg = await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is looking to go to {destination} and " 
                    "is looking for {number} other people to come.\n"
                    "When:\n {condition}\nReact with {thumbs_up} if you're interested! "
    await msg.add_reaction(thumbs_up)
                    "{ctx.guild.default_role.mention}")
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check_count_reaction(thumbs_up, number+1, msg))
    users = await reaction.users().flatten()
    users = [u for u in users if not u.bot]
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, {', '.join(m.mention for m in users)} are coming with you!")
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however, there were a few things that either I didn't understand or didn't work properly.
Things how they are now, the bot was saying:`@tag is looking to go to 1 and is looking for {number} other people to come.
When:
 {condition}
React with {thumbs_up} if you're interested! {ctx.guild.default_role.mention}`



This isn't a huge issue as I managed to fix it with some formatting. The bot also wasn't automatically reacting which I fixed myself. The main issue is there is no new message when "number" is met, so its also not tagging who reacted afterwards.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had to cache the message and then used the cache message to check for reactions. All working now, thank you! One last issue: since the bot is auto reacting to make it so people can only use that reaction, is there a way to hide the bots name in "x are coming with you!". I know why this is happening since it's looping through the entire thing, but I wonder if there's a way to hide the bot from showing at all? If not no big deal.

Comment: You would just need to remove it from that list: `users = [u for u in users if not u.bot]`

Comment: Sorry for all the comments I figured out that problem too. During the final print statement I changed `for m in users` to `for m in users[1:]` to start at [1] in that array instead of 0. Thank you for your help from earlier! EDIT:Oh I just noticed your response too. That probably works better. Thanks!